# ¿Cómo insertar valores de tipo bytearray en una base de datos?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un código en python que lee datos por serial provenientes de un xbee, los datos que lee tienen esta estructura: `digi.xbee.models.message.XBeeMessage(data, remote_device, timestamp, broadcast=False)` el dato que yo necesito esta en "data", cuando leo "data" me aparece así: `bytearray(b'  ArduinoB_Estacion3=1  ')`. Estoy intentando meter ese valor **"ArduinoB_Estacion3=1"** a una base de datos pero cuando se ejecuta no me lo inserta en la tabla.

**CÓDIGO:**

```
import time
import MySQLdb
import serial
from digi.xbee.devices import XBeeDevice

device = XBeeDevice('COM5', 9600)
device.open()
sql_conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='root',password='pass',host='localhost', 
database='xbee')
cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
print("Iniciando Conector XBEE")

while True:
    try:
        try:

            message = device.read_data(timeout=5)
            print(message.data)
            cursor.execute(
            """INSERT INTO xbeedata (name,num) VALUES 
(SUBSTRING_INDEX('%s','=',1),SUBSTRING_INDEX('%s','=',-1))""" % (
                message['data'].decode(), message['data'].decode()))
            sql_conn.commit()
        except Exception:
            print("")
        device.send_data_broadcast("XBee!")
        print("looping")
        time.sleep(0.01)   
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

sql_conn.close()
device.close()
```

**Tabla de la base de datos:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'xbeedata' (
  'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'name' varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  'num' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'tiempo' timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id')
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=162 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Te genera alguna excepción? Si no lo has probado quita ese print("") e imprime a excepción o el try anidado  y deja que se lance a excepción de producirse.

Comment: Además del error que da, tampoco estaría de más poner la estructura de la tabla. ¿Tienes activado el [modo estricto](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict)?

Comment: @FJSevilla, la excepción que me manda es la siguiente,  **XBeeMessage' object is not subscriptable** y esta es la tabla: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `xbeedata` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `num` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tiempo` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=162 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`

Comment: ¿No debería ser `message.data.decode()` en vez de `message['data'].decode()`?

Comment: O también `message.to_dict()["Data"].decode()` por lo que veo en el código fuente.

Comment: Listo, si funciono de esa manera, gracias @FJSevilla